# React js вывод данных в цикле

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
for (var i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement('div', {className: "message"}, mas[i]),
        document.getElementById('blockofMessages')
    ); 
}
```

Как можно вывести данные в цикле с помощью React, что бы он добавлял блоки а не перезаписывал данные в один и тот же блок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно *сначала* подготовить набор элементов для отображения, а уже *потом* выводить их в DOM-дереве через `ReactDOM.render`. Если вы не используете JSX, то ваш код может выглядеть так:

```
// Генерируем массив элементов для отображения.
var children = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    children.push(React.createElement('div', null, i));
}

// Отрисовываем элементы в DOM.
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement('div', null, children),
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

А вот и [рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/vb6moyb4/) на JSFiddle.

Если вам нужно отрисовать некий, заранее существующий массив в DOM, то вместо цикла `for` можно использовать функцию [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4];

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement('div', null, items.map(function(item) {
        return React.createElement('div', null, item);
    })),
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Ну а если вы используете JSX (и ES6), то код можно записать еще элегантнее:

```
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4];

ReactDOM.render(
    (<div>{items.map(item => <div>{item}</div>)}</div>),
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```